# Room Persistence won't delete full table row many-to-many relationship

Tags: android, kotlin, many-to-many, android-room, dao

I'm writing Android Tests using an "inMemoryDatabaseBuilder" for Room to make sure the @Delete annotation is working in the Dao (shown below, the assert looks different because I'm using Google's Truth library instead of JUnit), but while the list of groceries (List) are correctly being deleted, the parent GroceryList itself is not and still appears even though I've told Room/SQLite to delete the entire table row (which represents the relationship between a Food instance and GroceryList instance).

I've copied relevant info below:

**Android Test:**

```
 @Test
    fun deletePair_LWIDao() {
        runTest {
            sutDB.listDao().insertList(GroceryList(listId = 1, listName = "Grocery List A"))
            sutDB.groceryDao().insertFood(Food(foodId = 42, name = "apples", quantity = "5"))

            val listFood = ListFoodMap(1, 42)
            sutDB.listWithGroceriesDao().insertPair(listFood)
            val listWithGroceries = sutDB.listWithGroceriesDao().getAllListWithGroceries().first()

            assertThat(listWithGroceries.size).isEqualTo(1)

            sutDB.listWithGroceriesDao().deletePair(listFood)
            val lwgAfterDeletion = sutDB.listWithGroceriesDao().getAllListWithGroceries().first()

            assertThat(lwgAfterDeletion.size).isEqualTo(0)
        }
    }
```

**Base Data Classes:**

```
@Entity(tableName = "list_table")
data class GroceryList(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val listId: Long = 0,
    val listName: String,
    val visible: Boolean = true
) {}
```

```
@Entity(tableName = "food_table")
data class Food(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val foodId: Long = 0L,
    val name: String,
    val quantity: String,
    val category: String = "Uncategorized"
) {}
```

**Join Class:**

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = ["listId", "foodId"])
data class ListFoodMap(
    val listId: Long,
    val foodId: Long
)
```

**Returned Output Class:**

```
@Entity()
data class ListWithGroceries(
    @Embedded
    val list: GroceryList,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "listId",
        entityColumn = "foodId",
        associateBy = Junction(ListFoodMap::class)
    )
    val groceries: List<Food>
)
```

Dao:

```
@Dao
interface ListWithGroceriesDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insertPair(crossRef: ListFoodMap)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deletePair(crossRef: ListFoodMap)

    @Query("DELETE FROM ListFoodMap WHERE listId = :listId")
    suspend fun deleteSpecificListWithGroceries(listId: Long)

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM list_table")
    fun getAllListWithGroceries(): Flow<List<ListWithGroceries>>
```

Any help to understand either the problem or how to make sure the parent GroceryList instance is deleted as well as its associated list of grocery foods. Also, if it helps, the 3rd function (deleteSpecificListWithGroceries) has the same problem and will delete the List items, but not the GroceryList instance.